# views_get_view() returns an outdated view version

Tags: views, 6

I created a view setting *Items per page* to 10. `views_get_view()` shown ten nodes.

I have since changed the view and set *Items per page* to unlimited, and cleared the cache. `views_get_view()` still shows ten nodes.

The preview of that view shows more than ten nodes, so the view works as expected, but it uses only the *Default* display.

I also tried calling `views_get_view()` passing `TRUE` as second argument, which is supposed to ignore the cache. It did not change the number of nodes shown by `views_get_view()`.

How can I correctly show that view?

Comment: Does previewing the view show right thing?  Does the query from a preview match the query that gets used on the page.  You may need to install/enable Devel to see these.

Comment: Yes, previewing shows the right thing. With `$view = views_get_view('some_view'); $view->execute(); print_r($view)`, I can see that the query matches the one on the preview. I can also see that it has `[items_per_page] => 10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`views_get_view('some_view')` doesn't actually execute the View, it just retrieves the specification for the View.

How are you executing the view?

From the comment on your question, I see that you're doing:

```
$view = views_get_view('some_view');
$view->execute();
print_r($view);
```

On [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/341880#comment-1233538), merlinofchaos (the primary author of Views) recommends the following sequence:

```
$view = views_get_view('some_view');
$view->init_display();
$view->pre_execute();
$view->execute();
print_r($view);
```

which is roughly equivalent to this:

```
$view = views_get_view('some_view');
$view->preview();
print_r($view);
```

...except that the later also renders the view as HTML, which, if you're not going to use that rendered HTML, is wasteful.